# Set Cache-Control HTTP Header for S3 Objects from PHP AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I using the Amazon SDK for PHP and trying to set Cache-control Header on the image. When I try to add it via MetaData = array("Cache-Control") it changes it to be x-amz-meta-cache-control when I login to the S3 bucket, and when I download the file, there is no Cache-control set. But if I manually change this setting, the Cache-control works perfectly. Is there some parameter I missing that I can use to set HTTP Request Headers programmatically on upload? I'm using the PutObject method. I believe the AWS SDK is from 2013.

Comment: Can you please flag my answer as "accepted" if it helped you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The cache control isn't set via the "MetaData" index, "CacheControl" is at the same level as "MetaData", not contained within it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject

You'd use something like this as your configuration array for the putObject() method...

```
$s3client->putObject(array(
  'Bucket' => '...',
  'key' => '...',
  'body' => '...',
  'CacheControl' => 'max-age=172800',
  'MetaData' => array(
    'metaKey' => 'metaValue',
    'metaKey' => 'metaValue'
)));
```

For the upload() method...

```
$s3client->upload(
  'bucket',
  'key',
  fopen('sourcefile','r'),
  'public-read',
  array('params' => array(
    'CacheControl' => 'max-age=172800',
    'Metadata' => array(
      'metaKey' => 'metaValue',
      'metaKey' => 'metaValue'
))));
```

---

Also, it's worth pointing out that `upload()` will wrap `putObject()` for files of 5MB in size, otherwise it will initiate a multipart upload request.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to add the `CacheControl` header to an item already in your bucket, use the SDK's `copyObject` method. Set the `MetadataDirective` param to REPLACE to make the item overwrite itself.

I noticed one weird thing: I had to set the `ContentType` header too, even though it was already set. Otherwise the image would not display inline in the browser but be offered as a download.

```
$result = $s3->copyObject(array(
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'Bucket' => $bucket, // target bucket
    'CacheControl' => 'public, max-age=86400',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg', // !!
    'CopySource' => urlencode($bucket . '/' . $key),
    'Key' => $key, // target file name
    'MetadataDirective' => 'REPLACE'
));
```

Comment: Can you help me update the metadata of the existing object in laravel PHP.I have tried your solution but unable to update the metadata of the existing file.Thanks

Comment: For my case, it works without `urldecode` as `'CopySource' => "$bucket/$key"`